# Trigonometric integrals problem.

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I am trying to solve a stokes theorem verification problem, where i encountered a integral related to trigonometric function. Here is the integral:

$2\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2-sin^2t}.(-sint\; dt)$

I am failing to proceed forward. Where should i start with? I tried to use subsitution method like $let\; sint = u$ but it didn't work. Can u guys help me to proceed forward?

Answer (score 0):

Substitution:

$$u:=t-\pi\implies du=dt\implies\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2t}\,(-\sin t)dt=$$

$$=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2(u+\pi)}\,(-\sin(u+\pi))du=\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2u}\cdot\sin u\,du$$

and the above is the integral of an odd function on a symmetric interval, so...

Comment: so does it mean that the net output is zero? Because definite integral of an odd function is zero?

Comment: @user8668205 No. The definite integral **over a symmetric interval** of an odd integrable function equals zero.

Comment: sorry, i dont understand... what is this function $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2u}\cdot\sin u\,du$$ isn't it definite? or symmetric?

Comment: @user8668205 That is not a function but a definite integral...or Riemann integral, of an odd function over the symmetric interval $\;[-\pi,\,\pi]\;$ . I don't understand: what isn't clear?

Comment: i mean to say that the integral that i mentioned in the comment(which u derived) is definite and symmetrical...right?